# General term of sequences

Tags: calculus

Find the general term of a sequence $u_n$ defined by:
$$u_1=2$$ and for $n≥1$
$$u_{2n}= 7u_{2n-1}- 6\quad \&\quad 
u_{2n+1}= 7u_{2n}- 14$$

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial for formatting on this site.

Comment: What have you tried?  The general term clearly involves $7^{n-1}$.  Have you computed a bunch of terms?  Have you combined the two pieces into one recurrence for the odd numbers?

Comment: Thanks. I have found this sequence in determining the distribution of the list degrees of partial quotients of algebraic power series over a finite field so I need the general term of this sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Making $m = 2n$ we have

$$
u_{m+1}-7 u_m+14=0\\
u_m -7u_{m-1}+6=0
$$

and calling now $z_m = (u_m, u_{m-1})^{\dagger}$

$$
z_{m+1}-7 z_m = (-14,-6)^{\dagger}
$$

now solving for $z_m$

$$
z_m = (u_m, u_{m-1})^{\dagger} = 7^m(C_{01}, C_{02})^{\dagger}+\frac 16 (1-7^m)(14,6)^{\dagger}
$$

so we have two sequences: one for odd indexes and another for the even indexes. Now as we have $u_2 = 7u_1-6$ we can determine $C_{01}$ and $C_{02}$.

Comment: @ Cesareo  No, there are enough intial conditions: $u_1=2$ and from the first equation $u_2 = 7 u_1 - 6 = 14-6 = 8$. And the complete solution is $u_m=\frac{1}{42} \left(3 (-7)^m+2\ 7^m+91\right)$. The first few terms are $\{2,8,-6,288,-398\}$ If you wish you can view my formula as a unification of your two series. But, again, all terms are completely defined.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Yes. I agree with you. Thanks. I will edit conveniently.

Comment: Thanks. So  u_m=\frac{1}{42}(3(−7)^{m}+2 7^{m}+91) isn't the general term of this sequence?